# tools for running background tasks in asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, quartz.net, hangfire

I got confused on the correct design decision to execute background & long running tasks inside asp.net mvc web applications. now on these two links :-

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

&

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

they mentioned that it is risky to run background tasks and long running tasks inside asp.net web applications for the reasons they listed (mainly because IIS is not designed to run these types of tasks). but at the same time they listed some tools that can be installed inside the asp.net project to run background jobs such as quartz.net, WebBackgrounder , etc.

so i am not sure how these tool works ? for example if i install the WebBackgrounder inside my asp.net mvc web application (using nuget), and i deploy my asp.net mvc web application inside IIS ,, so will the jobs defined inside these tools run under IIS also ? or they will run independently of the IIs which is hosting the web application ?

Answer (score 1):

They will run on IIS, but in a different thread. What you need to achieve? Maybe you're trying to solve a problem in the wrong place. Consider decouple this task from your web app using message queue. Then, construct a service to consume messages from queue and compute what you need.

Here's a sample using azure service bus and worker roles, but you can use the same idea on premises:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/queue-centric-work-pattern

Comment: thanks for the help.. regarding what i am trying to achieve is that i have a method for scanning our network for servers & VM and update our DB , also the method runs some power shell & power cli scripts to scan the network. the scan might take around 10-15 minutes to complete. now i use to have this method as an action method inside my asp.net mvc, which can be called from a web browser, or on a timly basis as defined inside global.asax.

Comment: but from my reading and searching i found that that having such long running task inside an action method is not the best approach to follow. so i though that using tools such as quartz.net or webbackgrounder is the place to follow.... so can you adivce ? now as i said currently i have this as an action method which can be either started manually or on a timely basis as defined inside the global.asax file..

Comment: So, you start the powershell commands from your asp.net app, just that? I still recommend you decouple this process from your webapp. For example, start them from asp.net, but you don't need to wait until it ends. Change your powershell process to insert a message in a queue or something like that to notify you when it finishes.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my action method first will connect to a third part tool API using WebClient to get the scanning credential (username & password). After that it will execute the  powercli scripts, finally based on the powercli script result (such as the server network info) i will update the DB ,, also the system provides two approaches for scanning, either run a full scan based on time intervals or manually (in certain cases only ) or you can chose to scan only specific server,, so i need to wait for the scan till it ends..

Comment: i do understand that it is a more robust to have the scan as a separate .exe process ,, but on this link for example http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/ they listed how i can improve the robustness of executing long running tasks inside asp.net (of course still having this as a separate process is the best approach to follow) , but i am trying to find the most suitable approach in my case, since i did not write any windows service before...

Answer (score 1):

If you run Quartz.Net inside IIS then you're going to run into the same issues of IIS terminating the application periodically. When they mention using Quartz.Net what they are saying is that you install Quartz.Net as a windows service. Then your application talks to the Quartz.Net server that is running inside the service and schedules the jobs to run on it. The server/service then runs the jobs for you and you don't have the issues of running inside IIS, because your jobs are running inside the service.

There isn't a Quartz.Net nuget server package that can be installed as a windows service. For that you'll have to download the source and build it yourself or [download the binaries from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quartznet/files/quartznet/). The Quartz.Net nuget package is what you will use to schedule the jobs from your web application to the Quartz.Net server.

Comment: seems this is  a new area for me ,, so to follow the recommended approach then i have to convert my asp.net mvc action method into a windows service is this correct ? if yes , then can i inside the windows service to use entity framework, using webclient , run powercli scripts as i am currently doing inside my action method ?

Comment: You can run pretty much anything you want inside the service. One thing to be mindful of is that it is a separate process from your web app, so you won't have access to any of the in-process variables or context that you would have available in your action.

Comment: thanks for the point,, so how i will deal with this limitation ?

Comment: You need a place to put shared data in. Could be a database, a queue or something similar.